# Filter SharePoint user column using a user name in list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there a way to filter SharePoint user column by using user name, in **default** SharePoint list views?

For example, instead of `Created By is equal to [Me]`

Can we have `Created by is equal to vignesh.subramanian@ss.com` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The filter based on how you show the Create by filed. So you need to make the "Created by" column show field: work email to achieve this.

[image]